# Flutter transform rotate inside row / column

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, flutter-layout

I have a Column with some widgets inside.
If I trying to rotate one of them, it behaves like in the stack widget.
But I want to save layout of the rotated widget inside parent widget.
My question is how to revert (return) layout of the rotated widget inside Column, Row, etc... ?

The explanation and code example:

Right layout without rotation:

right layout screenshot

[image: right layout screenshot]

```
Column(
    children: [
        Text('Progress'),
        SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
        LinearProgressIndicator(
        value: _counter / 100,
        minHeight: 20,
        ),
    ],
)
```

Wrong layout with rotated widget:

wrong layout screenshot

[image]

```
Column(
  children: [
    Text('Progress'),
    SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
    Transform.rotate(
      angle: -45 / (180 / pi),
      child: LinearProgressIndicator(
        value: _counter / 100,
        minHeight: 20,
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

---

Wanted result screenshot

[image]

Thanks to Yeasin Sheikh for good idea,
task solved, final code [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=c10cb8b73a3633f16af9b0fc523c6283)

Comment: Have you tried increasing the height of the SizedBox in-between till you get what you need?

Comment: Something like:     SizedBox(height: 40.0) ?

Comment: I just was hoping there was a some widget that would wrap my rotated widget without manually calculating it actual size.

Answer (score 2):

Transform widget is just painting on UI, doesn't take actual space. You can wrap with SizedBox to provide the height.

[image]
If you can tweak the flexibility of your own from

```dart
 deg2Ran(double deg) => deg / (180 / pi);
 double boxHeight() {
    final value = (((500 * deg2Ran(angle))) / (deg2Ran(-45))).abs();
    return value < 20 ? 20.0 : value; // 20 your min height
  }
```

```dart
class SX extends StatefulWidget {
  const SX({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SX> createState() => _SXState();
}

class _SXState extends State<SX> {
  double angle = -45;

  deg2Ran(double deg) => deg / (180 / pi);

 double boxHeight() {
    final value = (((500 * deg2Ran(angle))) / (deg2Ran(-45))).abs();
    return value < 20 ? 20.0 : value; // 20 your min height
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Slider(
              min: -180,
              max: 180,
              value: angle,
              onChanged: (v) {
                setState(() {
                  angle = v;
                });
              }),
          Text('Progress'),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8.0,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: boxHeight(),
            child: Center(
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: deg2Ran(angle),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                  value: 22 / 100,
                  minHeight: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can handle overflow and some decoration